# Magento 2: How to hide address information during register new account

Tags: magento2, register

I don't remember where is option in backend how to hide fields with address information during reg new account.

[image]

Comment: might be a reference for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82229/hide-address-fileds-in-registration-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code for hide address information from customer registration form.

**Create file path in your theme and use this code:**

> app/design/frontend/Your_VendorName/Your_ThemeName/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_address_fields" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Let me know if any query.

Hope it help!